# Async nature of setState() not showing updated props from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

I understand that `setState()` is async by design in react, and I get why - because JS is single-threaded and so are browsers, therefore re-rendering is an expensive operation. I have a very (what seems to be) simple problem.

I am receiving some data from Firebase and I am setting that data to component state using `setState()`, so i can ship it off as props to the `About.js` component. What is happening is that the engine is skipping past the `setState()` (naturally) because of it's async nature and injecting the props into the `About.js` component. The props inside the `About.js` component are null, because it is receiving the initial props from the parent component which is set initially to null.

I tried the whole callback approach, but i am stuck on this little quirk (I hope they add an operation down the road to choose between sync and async for `setState()`).

Anyways, here's the code--- pretty simple. Thanks in advance for any help!

**`App.js`**

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        home_skills: null
    }

    this.sendSkillProps = this.sendSkillProps.bind(this);
}

sendSkillProps(delta) {
    return (previousState, currentProps) => {           
        return {...previousState, home_skills: delta}
    }
}

componentDidMount() {   

    // GET LIST HOME SKILLSET FROM FIREBASE
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    var skillset_ref = db.collection('SOME_COLLEC_ID').doc('SOME_DOC_ID');

    skillset_ref.onSnapshot((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            this.setState(this.sendSkillProps(doc.data()));
        } 

        else {              
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    });     

}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <MainSplash />
        <About madskills={this.state.home_skills} />
    </div>
    );
}} export default App;
```

**`About.js`**

```
export default class About extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {}
}

componentDidMount() {       
    console.log(this.props.madskills); // LOGS AS NULL  
}

render() {
    return (
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hussain.codes, this worked (thanks everyone else too!):

```
render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <MainSplash />
        {
            this.state.home_skills != null ? <About madskills={this.state.home_skills} /> : <h1>Loading...</h1>
        }
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your componentDidMount() at App.js file

```
componentDidMount() {   
    // GET LIST HOME SKILLSET FROM FIREBASE
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    var skillset_ref = db.collection('SOME_COLLEC_ID').doc('SOME_DOC_ID');

    skillset_ref.onSnapshot( async (doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            await this.setState(this.sendSkillProps(doc.data()));
        } 
        else {              
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this, will not work either, because I am getting an error in the console: `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`.

Comment: @ParthJ, My mistake i used async on componentDidMount instead of using on fat arrow function. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Really the async nature of setState is irrelevant here as far as I can tell. You seem to have over-complicated things. This should work:

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        home_skills: null
    }
}

componentDidMount() {   

    // GET LIST HOME SKILLSET FROM FIREBASE
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    var skillset_ref = db.collection('SOME_COLLEC_ID').doc('SOME_DOC_ID');

    skillset_ref.onSnapshot((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            this.setState({home_skills: doc.data()});
        } 

        else {              
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    });     

}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <MainSplash />
        <About madskills={this.state.home_skills} />
    </div>
    );
}} export default App;
```

Comment: Yeah, i understand that extra function was unnecessary (I was just trying out different things lol), but this still gives me null from the About.js component.

Comment: @ParthJ if your `<About/>` component is tightly dependent on `this.state.home_skills` then don't mount `<About/>` component untill `this.state.home_skills` has some value other than `null`.

Comment: @hussain.codes i like that idea, ill give it a try... thanks.